# How to create another table or Temp table with the Pivot query results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datatable, pivot, temp

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE COMPUTERS 
(
    CUSTOMER_ID INT, 
    COMPUTER_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
    COMPUTER_OS VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO COMPUTERS 
VALUES (15001, 'DESKTOP-JKVB','Windows 7'),
       (15001, 'DESKTOP-SKVB','Windows 2012R2'),
       (15002, 'PC-JKVB45','Windows VISTA'),
       (15002, 'JOHN-PC','Windows  10'),
       (15002, 'SERVER-DC','Windows 7'),
       (15002, 'DATA-PC','Windows 2016'),
       (15002, 'PC-BACKOFFICE','Windows 2008R2'),
       (15003, 'DESKTOP-XPBACK','Windows 7'),
       (15003, 'PC-HDFU','Windows  2012R2'),
       (15003, 'DESKTOP-NO2','Windows 10'),
       (15004, 'SERVER-DHCP','Windows 7'),
       (15004, 'DESKTOP-NO1','Windows 2012R2');
```

With the help of Stack overflow , i have written a query to pivot the above data.
My question is whether we can create a temp table or normal table with result of the pivot data.

PIVOT QUERY

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer_ID) AS Number
    FROM computers
),
cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.Customer_ID,
        c.Computer_Name,
        'Computer_Name_' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Computer
    FROM 
        cte AS c
),
cte_dist2 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID
    FROM computers
),
cte3 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        c.Customer_ID, c.Computer_OS,
        'Computer_OS_' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(100)) AS OS
    FROM 
        cte AS c
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    cd2.Customer_ID,
    MAX(IIF(c2.Computer='Computer_Name_1',c2.Computer_Name,NULL)) as Computer_Name_1,
    MAX(IIF(c3.OS='Computer_OS_1',c3.Computer_OS,NULL)) as Computer_OS_1,
    MAX(IIF(c2.Computer='Computer_Name_2',c2.Computer_Name,NULL)) as Computer_Name_2,
    MAX(IIF(c3.OS='Computer_OS_2',c3.Computer_OS,NULL)) as Computer_OS_2,
    MAX(IIF(c2.Computer='Computer_Name_3',c2.Computer_Name,NULL)) as Computer_Name_3,
    MAX(IIF(c3.OS='Computer_OS_3',c3.Computer_OS,NULL)) as Computer_OS_3,
    MAX(IIF(c2.Computer='Computer_Name_4',c2.Computer_Name,NULL)) as Computer_Name_4,
    MAX(IIF(c3.OS='Computer_OS_4',c3.Computer_OS,NULL)) as Computer_OS_4,
    MAX(IIF(c2.Computer='Computer_Name_5',c2.Computer_Name,NULL)) as Computer_Name_5,
    MAX(IIF(c3.OS='Computer_OS_5',c3.Computer_OS,NULL)) as Computer_OS_5
FROM 
    cte_dist2 AS cd2
INNER JOIN 
    cte2 AS c2 ON cd2.Customer_ID = c2.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN 
    cte3 AS c3 ON cd2.Customer_ID = c3.Customer_ID
GROUP BY 
    cd2.Customer_ID
```

Comment: Take a look at [`select into`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use temp tables below show two methods that you can use for creating temp tables

1. `select * into #temp from (--select query of the final cte function
   or query)` and temp table will be automatically create for you.
2. If you want to create your own temp table create temp table like below.

   **Eg**

   ```
   create table #Temp
   (
       EventID int, 
       EventTitle Varchar(50), 
       EventStartDate DateTime, 
       EventEndDate DatetIme, 
       EventEnumDays int,
       EventStartTime Datetime,
       EventEndTime DateTime, 
       EventRecurring Bit, 
       EventType int
   )
   ```

   and use `Insert Into #Temp --select query of the final cte function
   or query` will also work for you.